# Coloring white space in git-diff's output

Tags: git, colors, diff, whitespace

Regarding code formatting I'm kind of purist :). I very often remove unnecessary white spaces (lines with only ws, ws at the end of lines etc). I even have set vim to show that kind of lines colored to red.

My problem is that using git-diff I often see something like this:

```
-      else{ 
+      else{
```

Even if I have git-diff colored I can't see difference (in that particular situation I removed 1 ws at the end of line). Is there any way to tell git-diff to show that ws colored to red? (for example those matched with /\s+$/ regexp).

Comment: If you invert the colors (swap foreground and background), whitespace changes like this will show up. An easy way to accomplish this in many terminals is to highlight the text in question with the mouse. This trick only works with a colored diff, of course.

Comment: Use `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all`, as the accepted answer now explains at the top.

Comment: or if you don't want to permanently change your config (or like one-liners): `git -c diff.wsErrorHighlight="all" diff `

Answer (score 239, accepted):

With [with Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803980/6309) and after, you can do:

```
git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all
```

See [doc on `git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5272d304af3528163cd5faa822f88086448ae57/Documentation/diff-config.txt#L197-L201) and [on `git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5272d304af3528163cd5faa822f88086448ae57/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L311-L312).

---

For versions older than that, you can set the `color.diff.whitespace` config setting, e.g. with:

```
git config color.diff.whitespace "red reverse"
```

(I'm assuming that you already have `color.diff` or `color.ui` set to `auto` since you say that you see coloured patches from `git diff` anyway.)

If you want to fine tune the type of whitespace errors that are highlighted in red, you can then change `core.whitespace`, but `blank-at-eol` is enabled by default so you probably won't need to change that for the example you mention.

A possible source of confusion is that in the output of `git diff`, whitespace errors are only highlighted in the lines that are introduced, not those that are removed. (*Update:* as Paul Whittaker points out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509388/223092), which you should up-vote :), you can see these by reversing the sense of the diff with `git diff -R`.)

You can find more documentation on these config options in the [git config man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

If you don't want to use the `-R` kludge you can use the *WhiteSpace Error Highlight* option from the [diff man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

> --ws-error-highlight=
>
> Highlight whitespace errors on lines specified by  in the color specified by color.diff.whitespace.
>  is a comma
> separated list of old, new, context. When this option is not given,
> only whitespace errors in new lines are highlighted. E.g.
> --ws-error-highlight=new,old highlights whitespace errors on both deleted and added lines.  all can be used as a short-hand for
> old,new,context.

`git diff --ws-error-highlight=new,old <file>`

or

`git diff --ws-error-highlight=all <file>`

With versions older than 2.11, there’s no way to permanently turn this on and store this in config aside from using an alias:

`git config alias.df 'diff --ws-error-highlight=all'`

Now you can use:

`git df <file>`

To see the changes in red.

Comment: "A possible source of confusion is that in the output of git diff, whitespace errors are only highlighted in the lines that are introduced, not those that are removed." Exactly! And there is no way to show it also for removed lines? (hey, it's diff :))

Comment: Not as far as i know, but I could very easily have missed something.  I guess the logic is that since you're taking those lines out, who cares whether they had whitespace errors or not? :)

Comment: Add --global to set in your ~/.gitconfig

Comment: @radarek: you can use the reverse option: `git diff -R`

Comment: Is there a bug report for this? If not, it seems like there should be.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Is there a way to setup the git config so `git diff` will always run as if  `-R` was being added in the terminal?

Comment: I'd find that *very* confusing, personally! There's no such config option, I think, but you could create an alias to do it, e.g. `git config --global alias.diffr 'diff -R'` so then you can use `git diffr` for the reversed diff.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Solution is to use `git diff --ws-error-highlight=new,old`

Comment: this worked `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all`. Use `git config --global [...]` to make the changes global (ie affecting all repos).

Comment: I would have lead with "git config --global diff.wsErrorHighlight all".

Comment: Is there a way to show them also when using `git add -p`?

Comment: for those of you who like oneliners: `git -c diff.wsErrorHighlight="all" diff `

Answer (score 164):

Use `git diff -R` to turn removed lines into added lines.  Then trailing whitespace will be highlighted.

(This assumes you already have whitespace hightlighting enabled, as per the colour settings from Mark's answer.  Credit for this method goes to Junio's post at http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Highlighting-whitespace-on-removal-with-git-diff-td5653205.html .)

For example, when converting a file from DOS line endings to Unix, `git diff -R` clearly shows me the `^M` characters (dis)appearing at the ends of lines.  Without `-R` (and also without `-w` etc.) it shows that the entire file has changed, but doesn't show how.

Comment: Of course, you can also do `git diff | cat -A | less -S` if you're desperate, but in addition to the carriage returns, the `cat` will also display any colour highlighting escape codes literally.

Comment: @Paul_Whittaker `cat -A` isn't portable. On BSD cat, there is no such option. Please use `cat -vet` instead.

Answer (score 13):

For the lazy answer skimmers, just run:

```
git config --global diff.wsErrorHighlight all
```

Then `git diff` will highlight trailing whitespaces in removed lines as well.

Answer (score 12):

Use `git diff --color | less -R`. The `-R` makes the color control codes human-friendly.

Then you can use `less`'s regular expression search, e.g.

```
/[[:space:]]+$
```

Comment: This regular expression also works on `vim`, by the way.

Comment: This last idea of `less -R` just made it easier for me to pipe `ls --color` through `less`.

Answer (score 0):

My version of `git diff` already seems to do this - I have git 1.7.4.1 and have set `color.ui = auto`.

Comment: I just tested with git 1.7.5.1 and it certainly does not highlight trailing whitespace in lines being removed.

Answer (score 0):

The command mentioned above can also be included in the gitconfig
file as options, i.e instead of

```
git config ....
```

adding the corresponding options to e.g ~/.gitconfig

```
[diff]
    wsErrorHighlight = all

[color]
    ui = auto
```

the two options above should do the trick. The earliest git version I tested this was 1.7 but should work for any version after that too. On recent versions of git the "[color]" options is set to "auto" by default.