# Git false positives after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: git, ubuntu, gedit

Started a Git repository under Ubuntu 9.10. Finally upgraded to 10.04. Current Git is 1.7.0.4.

Now when I edit a file (with gedit) that was last changed before the upgrade, then commit, the commit is full of false-positive changes, ~400 lines out of ~1400.

I use spaces to indent within my source, if that matters.

Edit: a false-positive change looks like

```
- var a = 1;
+ var a = 1;
```

Edit: problem is CR/LF changed to LF, so question becomes how to suppress these on commit? (And maybe that's not advisable?)

Comment: What is a “false-positive change” supposed to be?

Comment: Check for whitespace (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output) or line endings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes) changes.

Comment: Thanks, see new Edit on the Q.

Comment: Are you working with windows developers? CR/LF is for windows, LF for linux. It's a bit strange that your repo used CR/LF.

Comment: Perhaps Gedit was using CR/LF in Javascript files, and its latest version doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [GitHub help](http://help.github.com/line-endings/) on the subject.

In your case, that would be setting this config value:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

This will convert everything to LF when committing. It may cause problems if your repository is expected to be in CR/LF.

If you're using Gedit, [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-line-ending-style-plugin/) would be nice to have in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If Git shows these lines as changed, something has changed. If you can’t see what has changed, it’s probably (in) the whitespace. Try viewing the diff in a hexdump (`git diff|hexdump -C`), this should show the differences a lot better.

Comment: `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`, `git diff --help` for more information, `git diff` has lots of options. `HEAD` is the most recent commit, `HEAD~` (or `HEAD~1`) would be its parent.