# Vim not highlighting whitespace in git patch

Tags: git, vim, macvim

I have followed the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output) for coloring white space in `git diff`s. However, I don't often use diffs, so this was helpful to me in something I do use often, `git add -p`, or patch mode. As of now, git will show me when I **add** a whitespace error. That is, it will highlight it on the end of a line. (I can't replicate this with a code example here because of the highlighting.) But when I **remove** a whitespace error, it looks like this:

```
-  def method_name
+  def method_name
```

Where there used to the a whitespace error on the end of the first line and it is deleted in the second. This isn't very helpful, because the lines look identical. So how can I get it to show the highlighting of a deleted whitespace error?

**Note: I am using MacVim.**

**EDIT:** The other issue is that if I try to `git diff -R` (reverse), then it looks like I *added* a whitespace error instead of removing it, and that's confusing.

Comment: In the link you referred, its says that there is no way to show if whitespace is removed. Only when its added can it be displayed.

Comment: how is this all related to vim?

Comment: I wasn't rejecting the possibility that it could be something with my `.vimrc` or something.

Comment: But vim is not part of this process at all? How is vim more related to this question than excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. All I have to offer are two mildly helpful tips:

- Regarding `git add`: If you see something like the situation you mentioned and
  you did not mess with tabs, you can be sure that you removed whitespace at
  the end of the line.
- Regarding `git diff -R`: Well, just remember that you are running `-R` :)