# Does JGit support .gitattributes?

Tags: eclipse, git, jgit

I'm trying to understand how to use the .gitattributes from JGit. But I'm unable to find any tutorial which best demonstrates it.

Is it that JGit hasn't support for it. But git client has this support. Why not JGit?

Comment: If I understand correct, JGit is only a library, that is you build a git client with it in java

Comment: @niceman:   Can you point me to some useful examples\tutorials for working with .gitattriebutes using  JGit ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse (with EGit that uses JGit) and I'm integrating GIT into it.

Comment: if you're on windows, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629396/cant-get-git-to-correctly-handle-crlf-problems-with-eclipse-launch-configs-xml) problem.
besides that any documentation/tutorial/example for git is good

Comment: like [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) documentation

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

JGit has basic support for .gitattributes. See [bug 342372](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372) and related bugs for the current state of development.

The JGit test suite may help you understanding how .gitattributes are implemented in JGit. See [this article](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/10/28/an-introduction-to-the-jgit-sources/) for how to work with the JGit sources.

Comment: Thanks, Can you point to some useful links from where I can get to know the usage of JGit attributes ?
I cannot find even a single link which illustrates the working behavior of JGit attributes

Comment: As far as there is support, .gitattributes behave the same in JGit and native Git. Hence you can use all the regular information about .gitattributes. If you find something is not working as described for native Git, you may want to file a [bug report](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I would like to know any self explanatory tutorial exists like [cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) which has self-explanatory code illustrating the various JGIT commands, Any tutorial\example exists from which I can learn how to play with JGit attributes ?

Comment: To understand 'various' JGit commands, you may want to read a getting started tutorial like this: http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/12/15/getting-started-with-jgit/

Comment: Yes, I have read that already. I'm asking if any similar tutorial (like cookbook) exists which illustrates about `org.eclipse.jgit.attributes`

Comment: I am not aware of any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115525/discussion-between-ragu-and-rudiger-herrmann).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try libgi2, there is [a jni bindings](https://github.com/git24j/git24j) that allows you to access most recent [libgit2 attributes apis](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/search/git_attr_)

Following are some examples:

```
Repository testRepo = Repository.open("path-to-your-repo");
// load macros from .gitattributes file
Attr.addMacro(testRepo, "binary", "-diff -crlf");
// Loop through all attributes
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
Attr.foreach(
        testRepo,
        EnumSet.of(CHECK_INDEX_THEN_FILE),
        ".",
        new Attr.ForeachCb() {
            @Override
            public int accept(String name, String value) {
                attributes.put(name, value);
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

You can find the test case about these apis [here](https://github.com/git24j/git24j/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/git24j/core/AttrTest.java)