# git add . modifying all the project

Tags: git, github, git-bash, github-for-windows

`git add .` should be adding files which are new and modified. I did change only 2 files and when I run `git status` command it shows me that the whole project is modified. What can be the problem? Thank you

[image]

Comment: you can check that by doing a `git diff`

Comment: I'd guess that it's a line-ending difference.

Comment: `git diff` shows me the specific changes made but still when I run `git add .`  and `git status` it shows me all the repo is modified and it is giving my partners a hard time finding where i made the changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git status shows files as changed even though contents are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Oliver mentioned in comments, it looks like its the line-ending difference.

To help you with that, I would quote two answeres :

First from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509629/4229514) on how to show line ending differences in `git diff` :

> First, make sure you're using the coloured output (e.g. with `git diff
>   --color`) and that you've enabled whitespace highlighting with (e.g.)
>
> ```
> git config color.diff.whitespace "red reverse"
> ```
>
> This might not work in all cases, however, as `git` doesn't appear to
>   highlight trailing whitespace for *removed* lines.  To see whitespace
>   that you've deleted, simply use
>
> ```
> git diff -R
> ```
>
> to put the whitespace on the 'added' side of the comparison, where it
>   does get highlighted.
>
> For more detail, see the answers at [this SO
>   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output).

And second from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889699/4229514) on how to fix the line-ending problem

> [GitHub suggests](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) that you should make sure to only use \n as a
>   newline character in git-handled repos. There's an option to
>   auto-convert:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf true
> ```
>
> Of course, this is said to convert crlf to lf, while you want to
>   convert cr to lf. I hope this still works …

NOTE : Please refer to the original question/answers to make sure they fit in with what you need, as git repos usually contain priceless data and messing with them is not a good idea unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with git diff to see what modification has been done, it can sometimes be ide which your using which may have caused some formatting in your files.

Comment: `git diff` is showing me only the specific changes I made