# wsErrorHighlight not working in gitconfig file

Tags: git, config, git-config

If I enter this command in the terminal: `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all` (from [Coloring white space in git-diff's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output).), then my `git diff` correctly shows removed whitespace highlighted in red.

But, for some reason, if I modify my ~/.gitconfig file to permanently have this change:

```
 [diff]
     # Automatically detect renames/moves of files in git diffs
     # Shows actual changes between files
     renames = true

     # Shows removed whitespace in diffs
     wsErrorHighlight = all
```

this doesn't work. Doing a `git diff` now doesn't show the removed whitespace highlighted in red.

Shouldn't these two ways produce the same result?

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you edit your question to include the version of Git you're using (`git --version`) and the output of `git config -l --show-origin | grep diff`?

Comment: @bk2204 Your `git config -l --show-origin | grep diff` helped me realize the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with the help of @bk2204.

I had originally ran `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all` and then `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight new` in order to reset the diff functionality back to the original.

But, the problem was that this actually added `diff.wserrorhighlight=new` to the local `.git/config` of the repo that I was testing this in, and this local config overrode the value from my global config that I had put `wsErrorHighlight = all` into.

So removing the line from the local config fixed this.