# git diff shows diffs for identical lines

Tags: git

I cloned a new repository and changed one line. The problem is that when I went to `git diff`, the diff also shows lines like the example below, where I haven't touched the line at all, and the diff shows... the same thing before and after the change? What's going on? How can I stop this?

```
@@ -22,8 +22,8 @@ class EventSpider(scrapy.Spider):

         next_page_links = response.xpath('//b[contains(text(), "Page")]/following-sibling::a/@href').getall()
         yield from response.follow_all(next_page_links, self.parse)
-
-    def parse_event(self, response):
+
+    def parse_event(self, response):
         def extract_from_xpath(query):
             return response.xpath(query).get(default='').strip()
```

Comment: Maybe the line endings are different? Or whitespace?

Comment: is there a way to make git diff show the whitespace characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coloring white space in git-diff's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output)

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the color for whitespace... something like this:

```sh
git config color.diff.whitespace "red reverse"
```