# How do you see if line endings changed in a commit on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is there any way to see CR characters in diffs in the GitHub web interface? (Apart from inferring from the new file size.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coloring white space in git-diff's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257553/coloring-white-space-in-git-diffs-output)

Comment: @scrappedcola It's helpful but my `git diff` already shows by default `^M` at the end of the lines where there is CR. My question was more specifically about whether there is some way/option to see the CR symbols in the GitHub web interface as I find it easier to mass-review files there.