# Verify line ending in git repo

Tags: git, line-endings

Is there any way to verify the line endings for a file in the git repo?  If I checkout then the working directory can be influenced by core.autocrlf or .gitattributes, etc.

Is there anything like "svn get" that doesn't checkout but simply copies a file from the repository to my local filesystem somewhere (assuming this ignores any line ending conversion settings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I checkout then the working directory can be influenced by core.autocrlf or .gitattributes, etc.

yes, it can.

> Is there anything like "svn get" that doesn't checkout but simply copies a file from the repository to my local filesystem somewhere

You can ask for a git archive of a repo: that is the files of a given commit compressed in an archive (zip or tar).
Some hosting services propose just that (like [GitHub and its `Download ZIP` button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583977/6309))

When you uncompressed such an archive, no eol is modified at all (it isn't a git repo, just a collection of files).