# Why are there changes in my working directory immediately after cloning in git?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo, then immediately ran `git status`

I am expecting my working directory to be clean instead I have changes not staged for commit.

Running `git reset --hard` does not clean my working directory

I ran `git checkout pe_oim_admin_2/runtime/prod/he1alxvpmid304/setcp_oim.sh`. I noticed the path changed for the file when running git status: `pe_oim_admin_2/runtime/Prod/he1alxvpmid304/setcp_oim.sh`. The Prod folder has an upper case now.

My git version is 1.9.5.msysgit.0. I updated to  2.9.0.windows.1 and am running into the same problem.

Any idea why git is behaving this way?

I've tried running git clone with core.autocrlf set to true and false.  I am getting the same behavior in both situations.

These two lines are in my .gitattributes file:

```
* text=auto
*.sh text
```

Comment: Might be a problem with Windows being case insensitive and all OSes being case sensitive.

Comment: have you tried to git clone it in a directory you haven't done it before in?

Comment: I tried it on my colleague's machine in a different directory.  Still had changes not staged for commit after running git status.

Comment: It's due to your 'autocrlf' setting (old and bad way to handle end of lines) . Solve it using '.gitattributes'. Nothing related but you should really update your git to the last version (1.9.5 had some bugs and new versions have some windows specific enhancements!)

Comment: Why 2.9.0? Why not the very latest 2.11?

Comment: My company network blocks s3.  That was the latest version they have available for download.

Answer (score 0):

First, on Windows, you can uncompress and use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): 
[`PortableGit-2.11.0.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.0.windows.3/PortableGit-2.11.0.3-64-bit.7z.exe) (auto-extractible exe)

Second, make sure to type (in any folder you want):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

Then clone again, and see if you still have changes in your `git status`.
See:

- "[Is there a way to determine the line endings in a existing git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824853/6309)"
- "[How to make git ignore changes in case?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116/6309)"