# Find the process updating a file in OSX

Tags: git, watch

I have got some files automatically modified in my git repository. `git status` shows them as modified. When I do `git reset --hard HEAD`, those files are still being shown as modified and current time as modified time.

Probably some process is modifying them. How to know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check the differences involve eol (end of line: lf vs. crlf), as [I do here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824853/6309):

```
git -c color.diff.whitespace="red reverse" diff -R -- aChangedFile
```

If would recommend setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`, and try to [renormalize the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309) (Git 2.16+)

```
git add --renormalize .
```

Then check your `git status`.

Comment: Its not crlf issue. There is some process seems to be updating the files. The changes are not trivial. Some meaningful content is there in the diffs.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Do you have an example of such modifications? Are you using XCode? What version of Git are you using?