# git tells me that my files are changed, but I can't see any difference

Tags: git, diff, tortoisegit

I've just installed the latest Git (1.9.5), and suddenly it tells me that my working tree is not clean (changes are not staged), but I can't see any changes in any of my files in any diff tool (I tried Tortoise and Visual Studio's built in). When I run git status, it says:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   inc/i_lab_orders.asp
        modified:   lab_order_list.asp
        modified:   slib/lab_order_lib.asp
```

However, Git GUI's diff tool tells me that all lines are changed, but I can't spot any difference. Same with the git bash's diff.

Running `git reset --hard` doesn't help at all -- the command executes w/o any problems, but in the end I still have the same "changed" files.

UPDATE: core.autocrlf is false, core.fileMode is also false. I also noticed that the files that are reported to be changed are exactly the ones that were committed in the last commit.

I'm on Windows.

Comment: My guess is that this has something to do with autocrlf.

Comment: `All lines are changed` is a good indicator for line-ending problems

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to hell. Enjoy your stay :-)

The difference that you can't see is the line ending. In a nutshell, you have told Git to convert all line endings to Windows or Unix and there is a file in the repo which has different line endings in the repo.

When you check out the file, Git does the conversion, creating a local file which looks correct. When you do a `diff`, Git doesn't convert (because the file on disk must be correct and why would it convert what is already in the repo?) and now you get differences which aren't there.

Solution: Make sure that Git is configured correctly for every developer who can `push`, commit the file once with the correct endings and get a silly hat for anyone to wear who creates files with wrong line endings.

Related:

- https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/
- [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)
- [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)

Comment: Thanks, that was my first thought. However, core.autocrlf is set to false (just checked). It always was. The problem started to happen after I upgraded.

Comment: Some tools like Eclipse's eGit ignore crucial line ending settings. So the first step is to check the file, then find out why it has the wrong line endings (go to the person who committed the file and check their tools).

Comment: Aaron, this person is myself, and I'm pretty sure the line endings are identical -- checked with Tortoise diff tool.

Comment: Unless you configure Git to highlight white space changes, you won't see line endings in most tools. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes

Answer (score 1):

Change may also be file mod, but you can tell git ignore something like this.

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

I recommend you use `gitk`

On ubuntu is just

```
sudo apt-get install gitk
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by manually deleting the .git\rebase-merge-failed folder. Thanks everybody for trying to help me.

**UPDATE** I also suspect that the cause was that I had `text=auto` in my .gitattributes file.