# Is there a GITS in GIT?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is there a Ghost in the Shell in GIT?

So someone commited from a different time zone and if I do:

```
git diff hiscom~1 hiscom
```

I get a huge diff of changes, like a day worth of work.

If I do git show hiscom, I see a few lines changed.
If I do git show hiscom~, I see a few lines changed.

His commit was in a totally different timezone, 12+ hours ahead of the repo / the last commit, then the commit after his was again normal.

Did something break in git?  I managed to go back about 24 hours worth of history and found the commit that should of been right before hiscom.  Its as if his commit jumped to the future and discarded all changes as if the branch reset to 24 hours ago.  The diff was nowhere to be seen on BitBucket, as bit bucket does git show not git diff hiscom~1 hiscom.

Any suggestions as to what to do to prevent this from happening in the future?

EDIT:  If I do checkout hiscom, then do git log. I can see the first commit after HEAD is correct. But at current HEAD in the branch hiscom is way out of order.

Comment: `git` will definitely not be confused by timezones. But remember things like merges can happen ... `git log` is likely to be more useful, also see `git reflog`.

Comment: Would a `git diff -w hiscom~1 hiscom` be shorted? (eol diffs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920650/6309)