# Why does GitHub highlight everyting when comparing code

Tags: github

When comparing, GitHub highlight everything as if I changed completely the code.
Is this normal?
http://puu.sh/sRRdy/4ad7599721.png

Comment: Instead of a picture, can you provide the Github link to the diff?

Comment: Probably CRLF/LF changes.

Comment: @Schwern, sorry, it's in a private repo

Comment: @PeeHaa do you know how can I fix this? I'm using PhpStorm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change line-ending settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings) or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-line-separators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first confirm this is an eol issue locally, [with your git showing eol diffrences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509629/6309).

```
git config color.diff.whitespace "red reverse"
git diff -R
```

If so:

- make sure git does not change anything for you

  ```
  git config --global core.autocrlf false,
  ```
- Configure your IDE to use the proper eol style
- clone again your repo and go on from there.