# How do I avoid making commits where a full file is shown as modified when there are only small changes in the file?

Tags: git

I run into this situation quite a lot and it really bothers the reviewer who is assigned to my pull request.

So basically what would happen is that I would add or delete couple of line(s) in the file and instead of showing that only change, it shows that the whole file is changed. How do I avoid those circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the nature of those differences.

[For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509629/6309):

```
git -c color.diff.whitespace="red reverse" diff -R -- afile
```

If they are eol-related (end of line characters), try cloning your repo again after a:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: You might also want to check to see if the local config has core.autocrlf set to true.   git config --local --list    and if it is true then use git config --local core.autocrlf false

Comment: @RandyLeberknight True. That is why I always suggest to re-clone (elsewhere locally). That way, no more previous local config interference.