# git commit 0 line add and remove end line also same but still show modified, what goes wrong?

Tags: git

I am using Windows - GitToitise.
When I do my git commit 
the file is 0 line add and remove.
[image]

I go to the git diff end line also same 
[image]

but still show modified, what goes wrong? 
I don't want to commit unedited file to my git repo.

My git config

```
git config core.fileMode false
git config core.autocrlf true
```

I download the source code from cPanel. and my working environment is Windows.

Comment: file permission

Comment: I also added `git config core.fileMode false` but still appear

Comment: One thing you could do is to check to verify if the files really are identical is to inspect the binary version of the file.

E.g., (assuming unix shell):
`cat wp-content/themes/index.php | hexdump` and
`git show HEAD:wp-content/themes/index.php | hexdump`

Are those hex dumps identical? If not, the files are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also added `git config core.fileMode false` but still appear

If `git -c color.diff.whitespace="red reverse" diff -R -- afile` shows anything (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509629/6309)), it is eol-related, and you would need to type:

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

And then clone *again* your repo in another folder, to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Be sure to follow the instruction from VonC to clone to a new folder. Just changing core.fileMode may not be sufficient.