# Why is npm 5.6 modifying package.json access time on Windows?

Tags: git, npm, package.json

Everytime time I run `npm install` in the git repository I am working on, the *package.json* file is considered modified by git and staged for commit even if the content given by `git diff` are identical.

After running `npm install` the modify time of package.json get updated though.

[image]

Comment: If it's staged for commit you have to use `git diff --cached`

Comment: I don't understand your comment @JoshLee. I don't want package.json to be staged for commit since  the content are identical before and after the command. It's not clear to me why `npm install` is modifying the _changed time_ of the file neither.

Comment: If git considers a file to be staged for commit, then the contents are different. If the contents were identical then git would not show the file as staged for commit.

Comment: To put it another way: There being a difference between the file at HEAD and the file in the staging area is _literally the definition_ of "staged for commit". So if you're wondering why npm is modifying your file, looking at _the actual changes_ is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I updated the post to illustrate that contents are identical. Just the mtime of the file is different. Would git consider mtime a difference?

Comment: Changing file attributes like modification time isn't enough to count as a diff. The only change you might see is that Windows has changed the permissions on the file, where you might see a diff like `old mode 100755 / new mode 100644`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes