# PhpStorm Version Control window shows files in "Local Changes" which have not been changed

Tags: git, phpstorm

Phpstorm: In the version control window in the "Local Changes" tab there are a lot of files which are actually not changed. When I go to the comparison view for such a file, it even says that the content is identical.
When I use git diff in a console, I also don't get any files as changed.
Does anybody have an idea?
Thx

Comment: Sounds like line endings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes) on how to visualize different line endings in `git diff`.

Comment: Thx kowsky, but in the question you linked to, git recognizes the changes and just doesn't highlight them well. In my case the files don't even appear under "git diff". They are really just there in Phpstorm.

Comment: could you please attach a screenshot of a Diff window for such a file?

Comment: Sure:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VRaoGow4obPFb6qusu4krjdlfKNh4wOu