# git diff shows same file as different

Tags: git, version-control

First of all, I'm new to git. 
I'm working on a branch (not master) and regularly merge with another branch. A few hours ago, everything was working fine, but I came across a problem.

I compared by using:
**git diff bc_integration origin/feature/ui** in bash (WSL).

```
    diff --git a/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js b/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
    index 41c1b42..f17de6d 100644
    --- a/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
    +++ b/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
    @@ -1,1671 +1,1671 @@
-/* =========================================================
- * bootstrap-datepicker.js
- * Repo: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/
```

The problem is I have two identical files but "diff" marks them as different. 
Not sure what is happening, but it may be related to me creating a backup folder, and replace my working directory with this backup (including the .git folder).

Comment: Okay, I did some testing, hashes are different (as shown in the above field), file sizes too. I think it might have something to do with CRLF and LF. Not sure how to fix it though or why git didn't properly convert.

Comment: I know think it is because I commited in Visual Studio Code and then again tested "git status" in bash and it showed me that many files were not staged, so I added them. And that is probably because VSC *will* convert CRLF to LF when pushing, but locally, there are still differences which bash recognizes.

Comment: Probably line ending difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920650/git-diff-show-me-line-ending-changes

Answer (score 0):

According to your case I think your that file permissions has been changed with last commit.
check file permission from following command in terminal:

```
ll
```

or

```
ls -al
```

Anyway please check your file permissions or if you didn't do any change with in that file you can reset it as last commit using :

```
git checkout js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
```

Comment: Read/write permissions were exactly the same.
What would checkout on a single file do?