# Git sees overriden file with identical content as entirely new file

Tags: git, file

I am currently working on a python application to save backups of system units from production.
For each unit there will be one backupfile which is basically a text file containing a dictionary of the configuration.

Now our idea was to use git instead of an increasing number of backup files (since we want to have a copy of every daily backup). Therefore for each unit we override the backup file with the new version and commit the changes. The problem is that git identifies every overwritten file as 100% change and registers a deletion and an insertion for every single line.

Is there any way to tell Git to ignore the file creation date or whatever it is looking at and just focus on content changes?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git status shows files as changed even though contents are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same)

Comment: This could be an issue with line endings. Try the options for git diff suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509629/86072), or open a diff viewer which highlights whitespace and line endings changes.

Comment: for the record : `git` *only* looks at a file's content, not at its modification time.