# git: fix CRLF mess retroactively

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

I mistakenly committed some files with the CRLF line endings.

Now I set `core.autocrlf = false` and fixed the files locally (in the editor).

Is there a way to fix this (e.g., using some combination of `rebase -i` &c) so that CRLF completely disappear from history permanently?

Comment: this seem to contain useful hints, hope it helps (see also the contained "renormalize" info): https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/#normalizing-line-endings-in-git-with-gitattributes

Comment: If you use `rebase -i`, you can always squash the commit that introduced the CRLFs with the one the removed them and there won't be a trace in history after that.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: how do I know which commit introduced CRLF? What if a commit that killed CRLFs was also doing something else?

Comment: Hopefully the list of possible commits isn't too long and you can check them individually with one of the commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3920650/5958842). Some Git UI tools also offer the possibility to see line endings in the diff.

Comment: Regarding the case where the commit "that killed CRLFs" is also doing something else, it depends. If it's important for you to keep each commit doing only one thing, then squashing won't work. You could instead use the "edit" option for the commit that introduced CRLFs and replace the CRLFs with LFs in an editor (or the command `dos2unix <filename>` is also an option). Note however that you might have some merge conflicts to resolve afterwards if you've edited the same lines in future commits.

Comment: In case `git rebase` with EOL transformation causes merge conflicts: I would use [git test fix](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/discussions/803). (I'm not posting an answer since I wasn't able to test it properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned:

- [`git add --renormalize .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309), which should help apply any `.gitattributes`/`git config` change.
- [`git ls-files --eol`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204436/6309), which help to list files with their EOL, for diagnostics.

Using a [`git rebase -x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt), you could call a script which would `git add --renormalize .`, to make sure your local Git config is applied.

---

[Guildenstern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725151/guildenstern) also points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962974/git-fix-crlf-mess-retroactively/77074392#comment135945349_76962974) to [`git test fix`](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/wiki/Command:-git-test#fixing-formatting-and-linting-issues)

> The `git test fix` subcommand can run command such as a formatter or linter and apply its resulting changes to each provided commit.
> For example: `git test fix --exec 'cargo fmt --all'`.
>
> ### Preventing merge conflicts
>
> It can be difficult to apply formatter or linter changes by hand (with e.g. `git rebase --exec`) because it necessarily rebases the descendants of fixed commits.
> This oftentimes causes merge conflicts that are about to be resolved by formatting or linting the next commit. (As a workaround, some people try fixing the commits in reverse topological order to minimize the chances of merge conflicts.)
>
> `git test fix` never produces merge conflicts because it fixes each commit in isolation by replacing its the tree OID directly, and leaves descendant commits otherwise unchanged. (You can do the same thing by hand by calling git amend with the `--reparent` option)

See `git test fix` [in action here](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/discussions/803).