git diff I cannot understand
Please look at this screenshot. I can't understand why github considers that I am removing (in red) and adding (in green) exactly the same lines.
Can someone help me understand what this actually means? Lines are identical, right?


First guess would be line endings, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3920650/3001761 for how to investigate.

yeah, thank you very much! You put me on the right track. Github was not showing whitespaces and that misled me.
